# How to launch a docker bundle with specified exposed ports?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

If you are not familiar with docker bundles please read [this.](https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-app-bundle/)

So I have tried to create a simple docker bundle from the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    image: cohenaj194/apache-simple
    ports:
      - 32701:80
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 32700:80
```

But the ports of the docker services this bundle created were not exposed and I could not access any of the containers in my services through ports 32700 or 32701 as I specified it in the`docker-compose.yml`.  How am I supposed to expose the ports of docker bundle services?

**Update:** I believe my issue may be that my `test.dab` file that is created with `docker-compose bundle` does not contain any mention of port 32700 or 32701:

```
{
  "Services": {
    "nginx": {
      "Image": "nginx@sha256:d33834dd25d330da75dccd8add3ae2c9d7bb97f502b421b02cecb6cb7b34a1b6", 
      "Networks": [
        "default"
      ], 
      "Ports": [
        {
          "Port": 80, 
          "Protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    "web": {
      "Image": "cohenaj194/apache-simple@sha256:6196c5bce25e5f76e0ea7cbe8e12e4e1f96bd36011ed37d3e4c5f06f6da95d69", 
      "Networks": [
        "default"
      ], 
      "Ports": [
        {
          "Port": 80, 
          "Protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "Version": "0.1"
}
```

Attempting to insert the extra ports into this file also does not work and results in the following error:

```
Error reading test.dab: JSON syntax error at byte 229: invalid character ':' after object key:value pair
```

**Update2:** My services are accessible over the default ports docker swarm assigns to services when the host port is not defined:

```
user@hostname:~/test$ docker service inspect test_nginx --pretty
ID:     3qimd4roft92w3es3qooa9qy8
Name:       test_nginx
Labels:
 - com.docker.stack.namespace=test
Mode:       Replicated
 Replicas:  2
Placement:
ContainerSpec:
 Image:     nginx@sha256:d33834dd25d330da75dccd8add3ae2c9d7bb97f502b421b02cecb6cb7b34a1b6
Networks: 1v5nyqqjnenf7xlti346qfw8n
Ports:
 Protocol = tcp
 TargetPort = 80
 PublishedPort = 30000
```

I can then get at my service from port 30000 however I want to be able to define the host port my services will use.

Comment: How did you check that the ports aren't accessible?

Comment: can you post the result of `docker ps` when it's started

Comment: Actually it is probably a problem with my docker bundle since there is no mention of port 32700 or 32701 in the generated `.dab` file

Comment: Also note that docker bundles deploy docker services.  Looking at a docker ps of a docker service is essentially pointless since ports of services are not bound to the host in the traditional manner or regular docker containers launched from the docker command line.

Answer (score 0):

As of the Docker 1.12 release, there is no way to specify a "published" port in the bundle. The bundle is a portable format, and exposed ports are non-portable (in that if two bundles used the same ones they would conflict).

So exposed ports will not be part of the bundle configuration. Currently the only option is to run a `docker service update` to add the published port. In the future there may be other ways to achieve this.